# Normalize function for train, test, and validation sets

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks

I am trying to normalize data for a neural network task.  I want to normalize the training set using this function:

```
normalize <- function(x) {
  return((x-min(x)) / (max(x)-min(x)))
}
```

so I can then use it in this way:

```
trainData1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(trainData, normalize))
```

I am new to writing functions in R and need a function to save the min/max from each column in the pre-normalized training set to then use in normalizing each column in the testing and validation sets.

My idea would be to write a function like:

```
normalize <- function(x, trainData) {
  return((x-min(trainData[,x])) / (max(trainData[,x]-min(trainData[,x]))
}
```

where trainData is already defined as a data.frame and has the same column names as the test data set.

When I run the function I get:

```
testData1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(testData, normalize))
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  argument "trainData" is missing, with no default
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like this might perhaps be better asked at stackoverflow, and there are R packages which do training and test data rescaling as part of machine learning, such as the `preProcess` function in the `caret` package

The following may not be the prettiest or fastest but it seems to produce more or less what you are looking for (`lapply` is just a loop, so if it is not working for you then consider using an explicit loop)

```
normalize <- function(newdataf, dataf){
  normalizeddataf <- newdataf 
  for (n in names(newdataf)){
     normalizeddataf[,n] <-  
         (newdataf[,n] - min(dataf[,n])) /  (max(dataf[,n]) -  min(dataf[,n]))
     } 
  return(normalizeddataf)
}
```

which given some toy numbers

```
trainData <- data.frame(a=c(4,7,9), b=c(19,11,12))
testData  <- data.frame(a=c(8,4),   b=c(14,15))
trainData1 <- normalize(trainData, trainData) 
testData1  <- normalize(testData,  trainData)
```

results in

```
> trainData1
    a     b
1 0.0 1.000
2 0.6 0.000
3 1.0 0.125
> testData1
    a     b
1 0.8 0.375
2 0.0 0.500
```

much as you might expect